# Why do my date entries reduce date values by 1?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

Here's my Java code:

```java
public class dtoAdapter{
    public FuelTab tabDtoToTabConverter(FuelTabDTO fuelTabDTO) {
        fuelTab.setPurchaseDate(stringToLocalDateConverter(fuelTabDTO.getPurchaseDate()));
       ...//some more setters
        return fuelTab;
    }

    private LocalDate stringToLocalDateConverter(String date){
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM.dd.yyyy");
        return LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    }
}
```

I have put in:

```
{
  "purchaseDate": "02.01.2018"
}
```

but the date in the database is 2018-01-31, so it reduced by 1 day. How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is the database column type?

Comment: Is it possible that the dates are not in the same timezone?

Comment: the column type in database is date;

Comment: here's my db source url - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db?useUnicode=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: my time zone is UTC+2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard dates are inserted as DateTime in SQL resulting in a Date autofilled with zeros:

> 02-01-2018 00:00:00

You should insert data with a timestamp `12:00:00` to fixyour problem
It might also be due to a difference between database timezone and local application timezone

Comment: Such blanket recommendations do not help. He's still not answered whether he uses `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` for storing dates, and what you suggest makes a lot of assumptions about timezones between appserver and the database. Your solution only works if they are exactly the same.